# UnsupportedClassVersionError when trying to build the platform

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to build the 1905 hybris platform but I keep getting this error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: de/hybris/ant/taskdefs/gradle/GenerateGradleProjectTask has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

I've tried to change the JAVA_HOME from system variables but didn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hybris 1905 needs Java 11. After you change `JAVA_HOME`, close the command-line / terminal (if it is open), and reopen it. In the command-line, do a `java -version`, and make sure it says Java 11.

Then inside the Hybris platform folder, run `setantenv.bat` (Windows) or `setantenv.sh` (Linux) before you build or start Hybris.

Comment: Thank you very much.